# Flink event-time session windows with max total time

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I was wondering if it's possible to create a `WindowAssigner` that is similar to:

```
EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.seconds(1L))
```

Except I don't want the window to keep growing in event-time on each element. I want the beginning of the window to be defined at the first element received (for that key), and end exactly 1 second later, no matter how many elements arrive in that second.

So it would probably look like this hypothetically:

```
EventTimeSessionWindows.withMax(Time.seconds(1L))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in window for this use case.

However, you can implement this with a [`GlobalWindow`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#global-windows), which collects all incoming elements, and a [`Trigger`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/windows.html#triggers) that registers a timer when an element is received and the window is empty, i.e., the first element or the first element after the window was purged. The window collects new elements until the timer fires. At that point, the window is evaluated and purged.

Comment: Does that timer have to be a processingTime timer rather than an eventTime timer? Otherwise if we receive 1 element for a key and then no others ever again, no other elements will trigger the onEventTime of the trigger I'm assuming, and the trigger will never fire?

Comment: Event-time timers are triggered by [watermarks](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/event_time.html#event-time-and-watermarks) which are global for all keys. As long as you have watermarks that make progress, the timers will fire. So you can use whichever timers fit your use case.