# Session window in Flink with fixed time

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a use case where I don't want the window for each key to keep on growing with each element. The requirement is to have a new window for each key that starts with the first element and ends exactly 1 minute later.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that it's your intention to collect all of the events that arrive for the same key within a minute of the first event, and then produce some result at the end of that minute.

This can be implemented in a pretty straightforward way with a `KeyedProcessFunction`. You can maintain `ListState` for each key, and append arriving records to the list. You can use a timer to trigger your end-of-window logic.

See [the tutorial on process functions from the Flink documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/learn-flink/event_driven/) for more.

Comment: Thanks @David this helps.                                                                                                Also, I found one more approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47799332/flink-event-time-session-windows-with-max-total-time using global windows and custom triggers.

Comment: Hi @David and s_k, would the solution suggested depend on actually receiving an event for the key after 1 minute? Basically, would the timer be checked for watermarks of all events, or just the events with the same key?

Comment: Timers are created on a per-key basis, but are triggered by watermarks, which depend on all of the events in that task slot (not just the events with the same key).